# Echoing out JavaScript with nested quotes from a PHP script onto an HTML page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ckeditor

I've been trying for about two hours to get the following code stored in a PHP string and then `echo`ed out as JavaScript on a webpage:

```
<div id="reply-box" style="display: block; width:100%;float:right;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/public/js/3rd_party/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Dynamic items */
        CKEDITOR.config.IPS_BBCODE          = {"acronym":{"id":"8","title":"Acronym","desc":"Allows you to make an acronym that will display a description when moused over","tag":"acronym","useoption":"1","example":"[acronym='Laugh Out Loud']lol[/acronym]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"Enter the description for this acronym (EG: Laugh Out Loud)","menu_content_text":"Enter the acronym (EG: lol)","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"ads1":{"id":"46","title":"ads1","desc":"","tag":"ads1","useoption":"0","example":"","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"1","optional_option":"0","image":""},"background":{"id":"27","title":"Background-color","desc":"Adds a background color behind the text","tag":"background","useoption":"1","example":"[background=red]Red background behind this text[/background]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"entry":{"id":"35","title":"Blog Entry Link","desc":"This tag provides an easy way to link to a blog entry.","tag":"entry","useoption":"1","example":"[entry=100]Click me![/entry]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"Entry ID","menu_content_text":"Text to display","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"blog":{"id":"34","title":"Blog Link","desc":"This tag provides an easy way to link to a blog.","tag":"blog","useoption":"1","example":"[blog=100]Click me![/blog]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"Blog ID","menu_content_text":"Text to display","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"code":{"id":"13","title":"Code","desc":"Allows you to enter general code","tag":"code","useoption":"0","example":"[code]$text = 'Some long code here';[/code]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"Code","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"extract":{"id":"33","title":"Extract Blog Entry","desc":"This will allow users to define an extract for an entry. Only this piece of the entry will be displayed on the main blog page and will show up in the RSS feed.","tag":"extract","useoption":"0","example":"[extract]This is an example![/extract]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"Blog entry extract","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"hr":{"id":"12","title":"Horizontal Rule","desc":"Adds a horizontal rule to separate text","tag":"hr","useoption":"0","example":"[hr]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"1","optional_option":"0","image":""},"html":{"id":"15","title":"HTML Code","desc":"Allows you to enter formatted/syntax-highlighted HTML code","tag":"html","useoption":"0","example":"[html]<div class='outer'>\n  <p>Hello World</p>\n </div>[/html]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"HTML Code","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"imgr":{"id":"39","title":"Image","desc":"Displays linked images, floating to the right","tag":"imgr","useoption":"0","example":"[imgr]http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif[/imgr]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"jump":{"id":"45","title":"jump","desc":"","tag":"jump","useoption":"0","example":"","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"media":{"id":"32","title":"Media","desc":"Allows a user to post media content from certain common media sites","tag":"media","useoption":"1","example":"[media]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqqLx-2vUr0[/media]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"Dimensions (Flash Only)","menu_content_text":"Media URL","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"1","image":""},"member":{"id":"31","title":"Member","desc":"Given a member name, a link is automatically generated to the member's profile","tag":"member","useoption":"1","example":"[member=admin] runs this site.","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"Member Name","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"1","optional_option":"0","image":""},"page":{"id":"38","title":"Multi-Page Articles","desc":"This tag can be used to create multi-page articles.  Page links are automatically added based on the number of times this tag is used, and the content is hidden until you reach the specified \"page\".","tag":"page","useoption":"0","example":"Content 1\n[page]\nContent 2\n[page]\nContent 3","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"1","optional_option":"0","image":""},"overline":{"id":"42","title":"Overlined Text","desc":"Makes the text overlined","tag":"overline","useoption":"0","example":"[overline]This text is underlined[/overline]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"php":{"id":"14","title":"PHP Code","desc":"Allows you to enter PHP code into a formatted/highlighted syntax box","tag":"php","useoption":"0","example":"[php]$variable = true;\n\nprint_r($variable);[/php]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"PHP Code","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"post":{"id":"6","title":"Post Link","desc":"This tag provides an easy way to link to a post.","tag":"post","useoption":"1","example":"[post=1]Click me![/post]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"Enter the Post ID","menu_content_text":"Enter the title for this link","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"pre":{"id":"43","title":"pre","desc":"","tag":"pre","useoption":"0","example":"","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"spoiler":{"id":"7","title":"Spoiler","desc":"Spoiler tag","tag":"spoiler","useoption":"0","example":"[spoiler]Some hidden text[/spoiler]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"Enter the text to be masked","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"sql":{"id":"16","title":"SQL Code","desc":"Allows you to enter formatted/syntax-highlighted SQL code","tag":"sql","useoption":"0","example":"[sql]SELECT p.*, t.* FROM posts p LEFT JOIN topics t ON t.tid=p.topic_id WHERE t.tid=7[/sql]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"SQL Commands","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"tab":{"id":"48","title":"tab","desc":"adds a tab (twelve spaces)","tag":"tab","useoption":"0","example":"[tab]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"1","optional_option":"0","image":""},"tex":{"id":"41","title":"tex","desc":"LaTeX","tag":"tex","useoption":"0","example":"","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"topic":{"id":"5","title":"Topic Link","desc":"This tag provides an easy way to link to a topic","tag":"topic","useoption":"1","example":"[topic=1]Click me![/topic]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"Enter the topic ID","menu_content_text":"Enter the title for this link","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""},"twitter":{"id":"36","title":"Twitter","desc":"A tag to link to a user's twitter account","tag":"twitter","useoption":"0","example":"[twitter]userName[/twitter]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"Twitter Username","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":"twitter.png"},"xml":{"id":"17","title":"XML Code","desc":"Allows you to enter formatted/syntax-highlighted XML code","tag":"xml","useoption":"0","example":"[xml]<outer>\n <inner>\n  <tag param='1'>Test</tag>\n </inner>\n</outer>[/xml]","switch_option":"0","menu_option_text":"","menu_content_text":"XML Code","single_tag":"0","optional_option":"0","image":""}};
        CKEDITOR.config.IPS_BBCODE_IMG_URL  = "http://example.com/public/style_extra/bbcode_icons";
        CKEDITOR.config.IPS_BBCODE_BUTTONS  = [];

        /* Has to go before config load */
        var IPS_smiley_path         = "http://example.com/public/style_emoticons/default/";
        var IPS_smiles              = {"total":20,"count":20,"emoticons":[{"src":"mellow.png","text":":mellow:"},{"src":"dry.png","text":"&lt;_&lt;"},{"src":"smile.png","text":":)"},{"src":"wub.png","text":":wub:"},{"src":"angry.png","text":":angry:"},{"src":"sad.png","text":":("},{"src":"unsure.png","text":":unsure:"},{"src":"wacko.png","text":":wacko:"},{"src":"blink.png","text":":blink:"},{"src":"sleep.png","text":"-_-"},{"src":"rolleyes.gif","text":":rolleyes:"},{"src":"huh.png","text":":huh:"},{"src":"happy.png","text":"^_^"},{"src":"ohmy.png","text":":o"},{"src":"wink.png","text":";)"},{"src":"tongue.png","text":":P"},{"src":"biggrin.png","text":":D"},{"src":"laugh.png","text":":lol:"},{"src":"cool.png","text":"B)"},{"src":"ph34r.png","text":":ph34r:"}]};
        var IPS_remove_plugins      = [];
        var IPS_hide_contextMenu    = 0;
        var IPS_rclick_contextMenu  = 0;

        /* Has to go after */

        /* Load our configuration */
        CKEDITOR.config.customConfig  = 'http://example.com/public/js/3rd_party/ckeditor/ips_config.js';
    </script>

    <input type='hidden' name='isRte' id='isRte_editor_4fe2476d708e8' value='1' />
    <textarea id="ipb_editor" name="Post" class='ipsEditor_textarea input_text'></textarea>
    <p class='desc ipsPad' style='display: none' id='editor_html_message_editor_4fe2476d708e8'></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ipb.textEditor.initialize('editor_4fe2476d708e8', { type: 'full',
                                                                height: 200,
                                                                minimize: 0,
                                                                bypassCKEditor: 0,
                                                                delayInit: 0,
                                                                isHtml: 0,
                                                                isRte: 1,
                                                                isTypingCallBack: '',
                                                                ips_AutoSaveKey: '',
                                                                ips_AutoSaveData: [] } );
    </script>
</div>
```

I've tried escaping quotes using several different JavaScript and PHP methods, but no matter what I try I can't get it echoed out without either breaking the page or the editor not working.

Does anyone know of a way to get this code stored in a string in a manner that can be then echoed out onto the page as working JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative way to write string literals in PHP? (without ' or ")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886899/alternative-way-to-write-string-literals-in-php-without-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php  ob_start(); ?>
<div id="reply-box" style="display: block; width:100%;float:right;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/public/js/3rd_party/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

.... your HTML/Javascript
</script>
</div>
<?php
      $string = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
?>
```

I don't have your javascript libs but it appears to show up fine when I echo out $string. PHP is basically copying all of the display content to a buffer and instead of rendering the page, we copy it to a variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
$variable = <<<END
xxx
xxx
xxx
END;

echo $variable;
```

Make sure you have END; on it's own line WITHOUT whitespace before it.

Hope have helped!

Comment: Obviously, echo if you don't need the variable to save memory!

Comment: Please explain - does it not work because it doesn't accept it as a variable, or because it still doesn't echo it out properly?